# Design CRM for using with a company and its partners

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

I need to design a model for CRM by which all cases be centralized for **the company** as well as **its partners**. It's a particular need that the company prepare service for its partners, also for the customers of each partner. Therefore, individuals in partners can be **contact** (because its account and entitlement is needed) and **user** (because they should have access to CRM similar to the company's supporters) at the same time.

Have you ever faced this need, and do you know a design model which cover it?

Answer (score 0):

The most general case would be to design your CRM-system around Contacts. You could then create a lookup from User to Contact, and create a workflow or plugin to ensure that a User always has a corresponding Contact created.

This way everyone is a Contact in the system, while some people also have User records.

Comment: Dear Henrik, customer in case can only be a contact or account, so in your solution we will have some activities come to a user and then some cases for these activities for the corresponding contacts. In users as From in activities users and their contacts as Customer in Cases. It's a kind of confusing.